# Удаление выделенной строчки в DataGridView из базы данных

Tags: c#, winforms

Помогите сделать так чтобы при нажатии на кнопку удалялась выделенная строчка в DataGridView из базы данных

Нашел в интернете ответ, но эта функция не удаляет из базы данных выбранные значение и при обновлении таблицы они вновь появляются

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow item in this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(item.Index);
        }
    }
```

Вот как подключаются данные к DataGridView

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        OracleDataAdapter oda = new OracleDataAdapter("select *from nebera_stadion", con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        oda.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        dataGridView1.Columns["id_stadion"].Visible = false; 
        con.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Индусы же наделали огромную кучу уроков на эту тему https://youtu.be/mdFgbdM8PYk или https://youtu.be/cQQy_IfFddg Хотя, я бы вам так писать не рекомендовал, ну то есть использовать `DataSet`,`DataAdapter`,`DataTable` из состава ADO.Net не нужно от слова совсем, а нужно создавать модель приложения из классов, а для привязки использовать `BindingSource`.

Comment: А как данные попадают в DataGridView? Используется привязка данных? Что является источником данных: коллекция объектов, DataTable или что? Как вы работаете с базой данных: сырой ADO.NET, micro-ORM типа Dapper, ORM типа EF?

Comment: Я указал как что есть источником данных

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы я могу удалить ту строку которая выделена в DataGridView из базы данных, чтобы при обновлении базы они не появлялись там снова

Comment: Ну, раз уж вы используете `DataAdapter`, то нужно вызвать его метод `Update`. При этом должны быть заданы свойства `UpdateCommand`, `DeleteCommand`.

Comment: [Обновление источников данных с объектами DataAdapter](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/updating-data-sources-with-dataadapters)

Answer (score 0):

```
delete * from table where id = 34
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// удаляет все записи из базы b_data_oper  выбранной Месяц и год 

sql = "delete * from b_data_oper where mes = '07' and year ='2020'";
cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.CommandText = sql;
try
{
    conn.Open();
    cmd.Prepare();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); //execute the mysql command
    conn.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
finally
{
    conn.Close();
    conn.Dispose();
}
```